# How can create a table with using filter on csv data

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create an html table from a csv using `d3.js`. Here is my code:

```
  d3.text('../data/satra_capitalasset_v_projectcount_m_b_enddate_executet.csv', function(data) {
    var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data).filter;


var sampleHTML = d3.select("body")
        .append("table")
        .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
        .style("border", "2px black solid")

        .selectAll("tr")
        .data(parsedCSV)
        .enter().append("tr")
        .selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d){return d;})
        .enter().append("td")
        .style("border", "1px black solid")
        .style("padding", "5px")
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "aliceblue")})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")})
        .text(function(d){return d;})
        .style("font-size", "12px");
});
```

It works now. But I need just some (not all) data of the csv file. So I need to use filter to have some data . My data is like this :

```
name   project   company   
a1       p1         c1   
a2       p2        c1  
a3       p3         c3
a4       p4         c1
```

Now I need just `company="c1"` && `project="p1"` from my data.So
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by use of Gillsa's comment(I'm not sure about name),this is answer:

```
   var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

   var filteredArray = parsedCSV.filter(function(obj) {
       //debugger;
       if (obj[1] == 'c1 ' && obj[3] == '‌p1') {

           return obj;

       }
```